# How to add taxonomy term to title tag in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, title, custom-taxonomy

I inherited a website that includes a custom post type (Cities). Due to some wonky url rewrites and redirects, SEO plugins won't work on those pages.

This custom post type has a taxonomy (States) and I need to insert the state name into the title tag in my header.php. I've tried the following, to no avail:

```
<title>Log Cabin Rentals in <?php single_term_title(); ?> - Find Your Dream Vacation Rental in <?php single_term_title(); ?></title>
```

I also tried:

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
echo '<title>Cash for Gold Near ' . $term->name . ' - Find Gold Buyers Near ' . $term->name .'</title>';
echo '<meta name="description" content="Looking for cash for gold near ' . $term->name . '? Our cash for gold directory helps you find reputable local gold buyers and pawnshops near  ' . $term->name . ', as well as info on how to earn the most cash for gold.">';
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Cynthia

Comment: Out of curiousity have you tried either single_cat_title() or single_tax_title() instead? It's tough to say exactly which you'll need without seeing the custom post type setup.

Comment: What ARE you getting though? Anything? Nothing? Any errors or warnings?

Can you try var_dump($term); and paste the result? I have a feeling the object might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot instead:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
echo $term->name;
```

If that echoes out your taxonomy name, you could replace the echoes in your title tag with $term->name

Comment: I tried it - see edits to the OP above - and no joy...ugh.

Comment: Strange! This might be a bit overkill, but I'm curious what query vars ARE getting passed, since these functions don't seem to be working. Can you place the following code in your header.php and paste the output? global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One:**

`get_terms()` - Retrieve the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

You can fully inject any customizations to the query before it is sent, as well as control the output with a filter.

The ‘get_terms’ filter will be called when the cache has the term and will pass the found term along with the array of $taxonomies and array of $args. This filter is also called before the array of terms is passed and will pass the array of terms, along with the $taxonomies and $args.

get_terms returns an array of objects. You cannot echo an array, if you do, you will just get `Array()`. What you can do is `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` to see the data it contains.

```
$taxonomy = 'shirt';
$args=array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
    echo $tax_term->name;
}
```

**Solution Two:**

You can use the function called `get_taxonomies()` in order to query out the taxonomy that you need.

**Syntax:**

```
<?php get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ) ?>
```

**Example:**

This example uses the 'object' output to retrieve and display the taxonomy called 'genre':

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'name' => 'genre'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or names
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}  
?>
```